# MySql: select a line inserted inside the same transaction before commit

Tags: mysql, transactions

In MySql using InnoDB, in the context of one transaction, are the inserts supposed to be visible by the following selects?

Example :

```
 $connect = new PDO('mysql:host='.  getConfig()->get('DB_HOST').';dbname='.  getConfig()-   >get('DB_NAME'), getConfig()->get('DB_USER'), getConfig()->get('DB_PASSWORD'), array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
 $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $connect->beginTransaction();

 $sql = 'INSERT INTO t_table (label) VALUES ("test") WHERE id = "1"';
 $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
 $query ->execute();

 $sql2='SELECT * FROM t_table';
 $query2=$connect->prepare($sql2);
 $query2->execute();
 $result = $query2->fetch();

 $connect->commit();
```

In this case, should 'test' be in $result? if not, how could I make it do so?

Precision: the column 'label' is not the primary key but has an index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, 'test' must be in $result.All operations in a single transaction are visible to each other.